# Domain transfer from godaddy to AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

On EC2 i just started a micro instance and installed ubuntu 14.04 with `php apache mysql`.Now i can access its from an ip like this `192.xxx.xx.xx`. Also i have domain name say `www.example.com` registered in godaddy and i just point my domain to this ip.My question is

1.Is it the correct way to transfer a domain from godaddy to AWS?

2.I heard  about amazon Route 53 service also used for this wahts the differnce between my method and Route 53 configurations

3.Also i have these  webmails say `admin@example.com`,`user@example.com` which i want to transfer to aws how can i transfer this? 
I am new AWS and DNS concepts

Comment: What's the necessity to transfer the domain?  You have raised email DNS, domain DNS.  Is public DNS essentially to your hosting at AWS?  Can your godaddy DNS still be hosted by godaddy now that your servers are hosted at AWS?

Comment: But i cannot  mange both of them so i need to move dns and server in aws

Comment: That does not make any sense to me.  Please provide more backstory and rather than just say, "I can't do that." please explain why.  Having all of the information allows for a real answer without any assumptions.

Comment: my godaddy DNS still be hosted by godaddy now i want to move DNS and host to AWS ec2

Comment: huh?  do you mean registration will stay with godaddy?  I'm no fan of AWS, but I'd choose them over godaddy.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Route 53 to handle the DNS and domain registration for your domain.  For docs on transferring domains check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html and since you are new to AWS you should probably read   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html too.

For your email concerns check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151382/setting-up-email-accounts-ec2 which boils down to you probably should let somebody else handle your email, like Google Apps for Domains.  Spammers make running your own email these days a very painful process.